# AWS: Can't create a trigger for CodeCommit -> Lambda (eu-central-1)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

Since AWS has enabled to have CodeCommit, CodeDeploy,... now available also in other regions, I have decided to move some of those services from eu-west-1 to **eu-central-1**, closer to home.

In the existing setup, I have created a lambda function which gets triggered when a commit is pushed to a CodeCommit repo and sends a nice notification about it to our Slack channel. It works, great.

But now, when I've tried to recreate the same functionality in **eu-central-1 (Frankfurt)**, I got stuck.

**I can't seem to create a trigger for CodeCommit to trigger a Lambda function. I've tried in some other regions and it works flawlessly.**

I know that:

- the rights, roles, policies and permissions are setup correctly
- it works in other regions
- the code **commit item is missing from the list** of triggers when you create a Lambda function
- If I try to create a trigger the other way around, starting from the code commit side, I get an error: 
  `AWS CodeCommit does not have access to the destination or the destination does not exist.`

Any idea if triggering has been forgotten during the implementation of CodeCommit in eu-central-1 or are there any other tricks I can try to get this working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that your Lambda function may be missing a policy which allows CodeCommit to invoke your function. If your new lambda function does not specify CodeCommit as a principal, they will not be able to invoke your function.

Usually, the easiest way to have this policy is by setting up your trigger in the Lambda console. Unfortunately, because CodeCommit is newly launched in these regions, this quick setup is not yet available. However, you can still follow the manual setup steps outlined here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-lambda-cc.html#how-to-notify-lam-perm

TLDR:

Create a json file 'AllowAccessfromMyDemoRepo.json':

```
{
    "FunctionName": "MyCodeCommitFunction", 
    "StatementId": "1", 
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction", 
    "Principal": "codecommit.amazonaws.com", 
    "SourceArn": "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-central-1:80398EXAMPLE:MyDemoRepo", 
    "SourceAccount": "80398EXAMPLE"
}
```

Run Lambda add-permission api:

```
aws lambda add-permission --cli-input-json file://AllowAccessfromMyDemoRepo.json
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked! Thank you very much. Meanwhile I temporarily solved it via CodeCommit -> SNS -> Lambda :) will gladly revert it now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not yet available at Frankfurt. maybe give a try in Ireland instead?

Comment: Just to be clear, Code Commit is available in Frankfurt. It is just the trigger function that seems to be forgotten.

I do have it in Ireland, but I want to have it in Frankfurt since the deploy chain Code Commit -> Code Pipeline etc... can only work with its local EC2 instances and I would like to have it closer to our customer base.

Comment: For what it's worth, the trigger setup is now available from the Lambda console (which configures the permissions by default), so hopefully this is an easy setup experience once again.